# jScrollPane - binding to events adds to all instances

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/events.html

In this example jscrollpane uses a class selector to bind functionality to the events. I cannot seem to bind to only one object:

```
 var pane = $('#scrollable');
pane.bind(
    'jsp-scroll-y',
    function (event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom) {
        if (isAtBottom) {
            $('#navigation').addClass('hiddenAtBottom');
        } else {
            $('#navigation').removeClass('hiddenAtBottom');
        }
        if (isAtTop) {
            $('#lioverview a').addClass('focus');
        } else {
            $('#lioverview a').removeClass('focus');
        }
        $('.content').each(function (i) {
            var ob = $(this);
            var offSet = ob.offset();
            var newOffset = (offSet.top - 150);
            if (newOffset <= 0) {
                $('#navigation a').removeClass('focus');
                $('#navigation li:eq(' + i + ') a').addClass('focus');
            }

        });
    }
);
pane.jScrollPane({
    animateScroll: true,
    animateDuration: 2500,
    animateEase: '',
    hijackInternalLinks: true
});
```

works as intended. If a add another scrollable area which I dont want the above to be bound to, I would think that I create another instance (and a seperate object)

something simple like

```
$('.accScrollable').jScrollPane();
```

Which, the scrollbars appear but every time I scroll to the bottom of these elements, the other bound function fires!

anyone know whats going on here?

regards

Comment: Your second selector `$('.accScrollable').jScrollPane()` binds to all elements with the class "accScrollable". Does `#scrollable` have that class?

Comment: nope, definately doesn't

Comment: Could you include your HTML as well?

Answer (score 1):

It sounded like what you were describing was a bug so I just put together a simple example to test. You can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/qSf2q/1/

Here is the javascript code:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();


$('#pane1').bind(
    'jsp-scroll-y',
    function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom)
    {
        console.log('#pane1 Handle jsp-scroll-y', this,
                        'scrollPositionY=', scrollPositionY,
                        'isAtTop=', isAtTop,
                        'isAtBottom=', isAtBottom);
    }
);
$('#pane2').bind(
    'jsp-scroll-y',
    function(event, scrollPositionY, isAtTop, isAtBottom)
    {
        console.log('#pane2 Handle jsp-scroll-y', this,
                        'scrollPositionY=', scrollPositionY,
                        'isAtTop=', isAtTop,
                        'isAtBottom=', isAtBottom);
    }
);
```

If you scroll #pane1 you will get the console message with #pane1 in it and if you scroll #pane2 you will get the message which starts with #pane2.

So it seems that the bug is with your code and not with jScrollPane. Since you don't include the whole code or a link to it we can't really help but hopefully this example shows you how you can bind listeners to different DOM elements...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qSf2q/5/ added my example. Seems like it being nested is the cause, any ideas on a fix?

Comment: I have added an explanation in the issue you raised on github which duplicates this question: https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler for `jsp-scroll-y` affects elements without a solid relation to the bound element `this`, in this case `#scrollable`.

Does you HTML contain multiple `#navigation`, `#lioverview` or `.content`?

Comment: .content is used in the first instance to detect how far down the page has been scrolled to each section to light up the navigation bar.

Comment: also adding an alert into the bound function fires the first instance html ($(this).html()) even when scrolling in the unrelated area.

Comment: Add `console.log('at bottom', this);` within `if (isAtBottom) { }` in your `jsp-scroll-y` event handler function. It should show you the current element when the event is triggered and `isAtBottom` is true.

Comment: yup, no matter the element, `at bottom <div id="scrollable" class="jspScrollable" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 1024px;" tabindex="0">` is the output

Comment: Make sure you have a valid HTML and that you´re not leaving any element open.